# Suppose P = BPP; Pseudorandom Generators vs NP Adversary

Tags: computational-complexity

Suppose P = [BPP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded-error_probabilistic_polynomial).

Then we know there exist pseudorandom number generators vs P.

Suppose the adversary is NP.

Now, any pseudorandom number generator that only uses P will fail. (Since NP can invert [one-way functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_way_function), and thus break any pseudorandom number generator based on them.)

Question:

How powerful do we have to allow the generator to be ([EXP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_time#Exponential_time)?) in order to generate a pseudorandom sequence that can fool NP?

Thanks!

[Context: reduced some open problem to this.]

[EDIT: Adversary does NOT have an NP oracle. Adversary is NP]

Comment: All these acornyms are standard in complexity theory. See Arora/Barak for example.